# What do the letters "ft." often seen on songs authors names - stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

What do the letters "ft." very often seen on songs authors names - stand for?

Don't Look Back In Anger - Vintage New Orleans Oasis Cover **ft.** Maiya Sykes ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OasxD_oP8M))

Answer (score 3):

It stands for **featuring**, where the definition of [feature](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/featuring) is "to give special prominence to."  In your example, Maiya Sykes is the singer who sings the words of the song and is thus the **featured artist** in that particular performance.

It is also used for a significant (but not necessarily the most prominent) solo.  For example, [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv6dMFF_yts) is titled *Fun.: We Are Young ft. Janelle Monáe*.  The primary musicians are the band *Fun.* and the lead singer sings most of the words, but it also **features** a prominent solo by the singer Janelle Monáe.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common abbreviation for "featuring". In the above case, the song name is "Don't Look Back In Anger", and it is performed (in this case, covered) by Postmodern Jukebox. The song also features Maiya Sykes, who presumably served an auxillary role in the music - this could mean she sang part of the song, played a solo on an instrument, or did anything that would put her in a highlighted role in the song while also not being the primary artist on the song.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer is incorrect - the video is by a group called "Postmodern Jukebox" that covers music in a very different style from the original version.  The song name is "Don't Look Back in Anger"; the original artist was the band "Oasis"; and the style they're using for the cover is "Vintage New Orleans."  Maiya Sykes did not serve an auxiliary role - she in fact sang the primary solo.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you for letting me know that PMJ was covering the original work. Although I stand by my use of "auxiliary"; PMJ is arguably the primary artist on this piece of music, and though Maiya Sykes does the lead vocals, it's not her song in the eyes of this music titling convention. It's PMJ's song (cover notwithstanding), she's just singing it.